# Change the threshold value of the keras RELU activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, relu

I am trying to change the threshold value of the activation function `Relu` while building my neural network.

So, the initial code was the one written below where the default value of the relu threshold is 0.

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(n_inputs, input_shape=(n_inputs, ), activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

However, Keras provides a function implementation of the same which can be reffered to [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/) and adding a screenshot as well.

[image]

So, I changed my code to the following to pass a custom function only to get the following error.

```
from keras.activations import relu
model = Sequential([
    Dense(n_inputs, input_shape=(n_inputs, ), activation = relu(threshold = 2)), 
    Dense(32, activation = relu(threshold = 2)),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

**Error:** `TypeError: relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

I understand the error is that I am not using x in the relu function but there is no way for me to pass something like that. The syntax expects me to write `model.add(layers.Activation(activations.relu))` but then I won't be able to change the threshold. This is where I need a workaround or solution.

I then used the [Layer implementation of the ReLU function](https://keras.io/api/layers/activation_layers/relu/) which worked for me as written below but I want to find out if there is a way I can make the activation function implementation work because the layer is not always convenient to add and I want to make more modifications inside the Dense function.

**Code which worked for me:-**

```
from keras.layers import ReLU
model = Sequential([
    Dense(n_inputs, input_shape=(n_inputs, )),
    ReLU(threshold=4), 
    Dense(32),
    ReLU(threshold=4),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're facing is reasonable. However, you can use the following trick on the `relu` function for your work. In this way, you define a function that takes necessary arguments e.g `alpha`, `threshold` etc, and in the function body, you define another function that calculates **`relu`**  activations with these parameters, and the end returns to the upper function.

```
# help(tf.keras.backend.relu)
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
def relu_advanced(alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0):        
    def relu_plus(x):
        return K.relu(x, 
                      alpha = tf.cast(alpha, tf.float32), 
                      max_value = max_value,
                      threshold= tf.cast(threshold, tf.float32))
    return relu_plus
```

Samples:

```
foo = tf.constant([-10, -5, 0.0, 5, 10], dtype = tf.float32)
tf.keras.activations.relu(foo).numpy()
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  5., 10.], dtype=float32)

x = relu_advanced(threshold=1)
x(foo).numpy()
array([-0., -0.,  0.,  5., 10.], dtype=float32)
```

For your case, simply use as follows:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(64, input_shape=(32, ), activation = relu_advanced(threshold=2)), 
    Dense(32, activation = relu_advanced(threshold=2)),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: What's the role of ````alpha```` and ````max_value```` inside the function?

Comment: ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/relu#args_1