# How do I change activation function parametrs within Keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to add a neuron layer to my model which has [tf.keras.activations.relu()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/relu) with max_value = 1 as its activation function. When I try doing it like this:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,  activation=tf.keras.activations.relu(max_value=1)))
```

It gives me following error:

```
TypeError: relu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I don't have any x to give it, obviously, as I am just trying to set up a neuron layer. Is there a way to customize these activation functions properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the threshold value of the keras RELU activation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450580/change-the-threshold-value-of-the-keras-relu-activation-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `x` is the input tensor to activation function in order to activate it.

Based on [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ReLU) for `relu`, you can use `relu` as a separate layer. To do this you can modify your code like this:

```
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=1))
```